# Problem with mysql LIMIT and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to do the dreaded pagination using PDO, but I can't find an answer fitting my situation:

```
    $pageVar = 10;
    $startRowLimit = ($page * $pageVar) - $pageVar; // returns correct value 

$articlesQuery = "SELECT 
`ID`,`Title`,`Text`,`Poster`,`Date`,
( SELECT `ID` FROM users WHERE article.`Poster` = users.`Username` )
FROM article WHERE `Visible` = 1 ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT ? , ? ";

$articles = $mysqli->selectAll($articlesQuery, array($startRowLimit, $pageVar));
```

Here's selectAll function:

```
        public function selectAll($query, $params){

        $this->sql = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $this->sql->execute($params);
        $result = $this->sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;

    }
```

How can I make it work? I tried doing

```
array((int) $startRowLimit, (int) $pageVar)
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Do you think it's a PHP issue because the SQL code itself works? And, how exactly is it not working?

Comment: Alvaro - the SQL code works fine in phpMyAdmin. It just doesn't display any results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use mark for limit since they doens't come from user input. Just put your int variables in the query

```
DESC LIMIT {$offset} , {$var}
```

Anyway the right syntax is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * [...] LIMIT :start, :results";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $_GET['start'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':results', $_GET['results'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing you did without changing or creating a new function in my db class?

Comment: I posted the selectAll function in the question as you can see, any way to modify that function to make it work?

Comment: @crembo: i posted the code in my answer, what part isn't clear?